# angular2-multiselect [data] is loading data very slow

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<angular2-multiselect [data]="listAllCategories" #serviceSubCategoryLists
                  [settings]="serviceTypeSettings ">
```

angular2-multiselect [data]="List" loads very slow to dropdown if list is having 1000+ items.

Comment: can you plz share serviceTypeSettings with us?

Comment: use ng-select library assign property [virtualScroll]="true". Refer to url for implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `lazyLoading` in your settings. Which loads data from API asynchronously.

```
serviceTypeSettings = {
lazyLoading: true
}
```

plz refer: 
https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-multiselect-dropdown/#/lazyloadingRemoteData

Comment: thanks after adding {lazyLoading:true}  now Page Multiselects are   lot faster than before.

Comment: After adding Lazy Loading search filter Won't Work??           
 this.serviceTypeSettings = {
      singleSelection: false, text: "Select", enableSearchFilter: true, selectAllText: 'Select All', enableFilterSelectAll: false,
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All', badgeShowLimit: 1, noDataLabel: null, isSelectAll: true, includeSelectAllOption: true,lazyLoading: true
    };

Comment: Search filter has to work maybe you are missing something, you can see in lazyload example search filter is working, likewise yours should work plz cross check patiently.
Kindly accept this answer if it really helped solving your problem.

Comment: since i was pushing whole list once it was not working tried with concatinating whole new data to  current list filtering works fine.thanks:)

Comment: Happy to help in solving your problem. Accept  this answer if it really helped solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where is data coming from?
if you use an API, please check it with Postman, maybe it took time in API layer or server side app